# unsupported format character '_' (0x5f)

Tags: django

**models.py**

```
class ChangingDocument(PrivateCommentMixin,
                       models.Model):

    # Список изменяющих документов.
    treaty = models.ForeignKey("treaties.Treaty",
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               blank=False,
                               null=False,
                               related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
                               related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss", )

    changing_document = models.ForeignKey("treaties.Treaty",
                                          on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                          blank=False,
                                          null=False,
                                          related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)_changing_documents_related",
                                          related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss_changing_documents", )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.changing_document)
```

**Stack trace**

```
(venv) michael@michael:/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/treaty_project$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/treaty_project/changing_documents/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class ChangingDocument(PrivateCommentMixin,
  File "/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 194, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 866, in contribute_to_class
    super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, private_only=private_only, **kwargs)
  File "/media/michael/750/Programming/treaty_outer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 357, in contribute_to_class
    related_name %= {
ValueError: unsupported format character '_' (0x5f) at index 22
```

**Problem**

I have done the model by example from here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)_changing_documents_related'` you forgot an `s` after the `%(class)`, so the formatter does not know how to format the `class` string (as string `s`, or as repr `r`, or something else). You thus need to add an `s` *before* the underscore, so:

```
related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_changing_documents_related'
```

In short, using `%(var_name)` is *not* enough, you work with a `%(var_name)specifier`, where the specifier is ofter `s` or `r`. For `r`, it will call `repr` instead, so:

```
>>> '%(app_label)s_%(class)r_changing_documents_related' % {'app_label': 'app_label', 'class': 'class'}
"app_label_'class'_changing_documents_related"
```

will pass `'class'` through `repr`, and thus add additional quotes. Here that does not make much sense to do however.